# Client-Side Object Recognition

Tags: offline, image-processing, object-recognition

I am tasked with object recognition for images offline (for contractual reasons).  This means that I cannot use services like Microsoft Cognition or Google Cloud Vision.  I do not know if there are any products where I do not need to upload my image to an external server, or if this is even feasible.

- Must recognize objects such as a pencil, person, computer, or hotdog.
- Image cannot be uploaded to an external server at any point.
- Must run on Windows 10.
- Accuracy is of medium to high importance.
- Roughly $250 max price point.
- Speed performance is irrelevant.

What is an offline object recognition software that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://imageai.org/

It does not have the best database, but it does the job in a pinch.  It uses TensorFlow and OpenCV.

The only 80 objects it can recognize are:

```
  person, bicycle, car, motorcycle, airplane, bus, train, truck, boat, traffic light, fire hydrant, stop_sign,
  parking meter,   bench,   bird,   cat,   dog,   horse,   sheep,   cow,   elephant,   bear,   zebra,
  giraffe,   backpack,   umbrella,   handbag,   tie,   suitcase,   frisbee,   skis,   snowboard,
  sports ball,   kite,   baseball bat,   baseball glove,   skateboard,   surfboard,   tennis racket,
  bottle,   wine glass,   cup,   fork,   knife,   spoon,   bowl,   banana,   apple,   sandwich,   orange,
  broccoli,   carrot,   hot dog,   pizza,   donot,   cake,   chair,   couch,   potted plant,   bed,
  dining table,   toilet,   tv,   laptop,   mouse,   remote,   keyboard,   cell phone,   microwave,
  oven,   toaster,   sink,   refrigerator,   book,   clock,   vase,   scissors,   teddy bear,   hair dryer,
  toothbrush.
```